# Is introspection considered a form of empirical experience?

Tags: empiricism, experience, introspection

In my philosophical readings, it appears there is no consensus on this issue among some of the great philosophical minds, or given differences in their expressions I don't perceive a consensus. Normally, I would interpret the canon roughly as classical empiricism committing itself to sense data about the world as being the basis of empirical evidence. And yet, in a way, conscious introspection is extremely derivative of sense data about the world. It seems to me, someone not heavily invested in Continental thinking, that phenomenological reduction might be considered empirical in nature, but even on the analytical side, if one introspects informed by cognitive science, that might be considered empirical.

**So, according to contemporary philosophical views, is introspection considered a form of empirical experience?**

Comment: IEP - https://iep.utm.edu/introspe - *Introspection is the process by which someone comes to form beliefs about her own mental states.* Is this the empirical meaning of introspection?  The definition does not conform to my experience of forming beliefs since all my mental states, including my beliefs or beliefs about mental states, apparently form automatically as the product of an unconscious process.  Take the apparent motion of the Sun and stars. One belief is they revolve around earth. Another is earth spins on its axis and revolves around the Sun. Introspection is to observe and compare.

Comment: phenomenology was meant, iirc, to rage against introspection and its falliability.

Comment: The [SEP entry on apriority](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/apriori/) reads: "Observations based on our senses, or introspection about our current mental state, are needed for us to be empirically, or *a posteriori*, justified in believing that some proposition is true," and otherwise has introspection as empirical. This is ultimately because we are in a sense quasi-passively related to knowledge by introspection, whereas truly *a priori* knowledge is more "proactive" or "spontaneous" (Kant's word).

Comment: @SystemTheory -- I think we should separate *ideas* (a.k.a. Locke's simple ideas, a.k.a. Kant's intuitions) and *models* (Locke's complex ideas or Kant's concepts). The former are indeed the product of an unconscious process, we form them automatically. The latter, however, we put together through conscious effort. It's a trainable skill too -- that is, in the beginning, it might take a whole lot of effort with very little to show for it. Often, this is enough to discourage the person from learning the art.

Comment: It surely is. Psychologists [routinely use](https://philarchive.org/archive/HATIEI) introspective reports from their subjects and stage experiments to induce material for such reports. However, at least since Kant, reliability of introspection is considered qualitatively inferior to that of sense perception, which explains why empiricists treat it with thick gloves. This said, see [Peels](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43895571) and [Piccinini](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/497/1/Publicityofintrospection_phil-sci.docof) critiquing anti-introspection arguments.

Comment: @Conifold The introspective skills I use to practice electrical engineering (applied physics) are the same for the analysis of patterns of human drama (applied social psychology). Both require the mix of memories of sense perception with concepts that form apriori (instinct) or that seem to emerge as the products of a learning process. The criterion of truth seems to be coherence of concepts in the sensory context. Helmholtz describes perception as unconscious inference. Freud maps ego conflict to repressed sensory memories. A psychoanalyst spins up conscious models of other unconscious minds!

Comment: Essentially, we model and predict, then adjust our models each time results come in. It's like a video game turned inside out.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT - Introspection is sufficient to conclude that empirical experience is impossible without the human capacity for introspection.

Sometime around 1999 John Guarnaschelli - https://www.youtube.com/@dr.johnguarnaschelli441/videos - expresses his thoughts as follows. "The Latin roots of the word, consciousness, mean with-knowledge". He talks about the lack of knowledge, lacuna, or gaps in our introspective capacities, and says, "I only know what I've experienced." And I thought, "Consciously!".

We can build instruments that make empirical measurements using physical mechanisms that we also associate with our sense data but the instruments do not know if they are properly calibrated or not to our standard units of measure. A control system with the wrong parameters or uncalibrated instruments will malfunction even though it is operating on what we regard as sense data. Introspection is required to comprehend all of these ideas relating to empirical models.

I once argued with a chemist concerning his effort to measure the power developed by his 1/10 scale electric race cars using a dyno. He thought the current measurement given by the sensor must be accurate. I had to show him the datasheet for his current sensor had a cut-off of 100 amperes but the mechanical performance of his race car at 8.4 volts battery would require more like 200 amperes starting current! The human ego, effort to govern action in the sensory context, has a power of introspection which generates the ability to judge vaguely whether a result is or is not the product of an empirical process.

*Sense data about the (external) world is the basis for empirical evidence.*

Introspection is sufficient to form the belief that sense data has no empirical meaning independent of one's other mental states. Simply imagine that one could suspend or take away the process of making empirical observations and measurements and allow that the sensory information could pass by the mind's eye like water flowing in a stream. The sensory experience may be necessary to call a mental process "empirical" but concepts must form as well and those concepts and the sensory perceptions are all objects of introspection not attributes of the external world.

EDIT - ADDITIONAL MATERIAL

Introspection in my experience is necessary to practice empirical science in the context of social psychology. One must be conscious of social psychology to recognize Galileo as "the "father of modern science" and to learn how to imitate his empirical methods.

https://www.nmspacemuseum.org/inductee/galileo-galilei/

> Galileo Galilei pioneered the experimental scientific method and was the first to use a refracting telescope to make important astronomical discoveries. He is often referred to as the “father of modern astronomy” and the “father of modern physics”. Albert Einstein called Galileo the “father of modern science.”

When I contemplate empirical measurements I consult The NIST Guide to the SI, Chapter 4: The Two Classes of the SI Units and the SI Prefixes

https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-chapter-4-two-classes-si-units-and-si-prefixes

Galileo used his observations of sensory perceptions to make compelling arguments against the stationary earth hypothesis. The apparent motion of the Sun and stars is revolving around the earth.
Galileo used sensory perceptions with the aid of his telescope to find evidence and compelling arguments for the Capenican model of the earth revolving around the Sun.

Galileo made new math models to define physical quantities and he applied empirical measurement methods to specify the values of quantities in a specified sensory context. The primary example of empirical measurements, for me, is when Galileo rolls balls down a ramp and across a horizontal surface. He defines position, time, displacement, speed, and acceleration with methods to measure time and position and to derive the other physical quantities using his math model. This is a paradigm for all of our modern empirical measurement models. Introspection is required to apply the paradigm in the empirical context.

Answer (score 1):

The entry [Introspection](https://iep.utm.edu/introspe) of the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy comprises in its chapter “The Nature of Introspection “ the two sections

> Observational Models, Non-observational Models.

- Ad observational models: “just as our perceptual capacity
  enables us to observe the outer world, our introspective capacity
  enables us to observe the inner world.” This philosophical position
  is considered also the viewpoint of Locke. Because introspection is
  a first-person view the result cannot be verified by other persons
  from the third-person view.

  I conclude: Even when introspection is an
  empirical method, the results are not intrasubjectively testable. Which
  is a severe handicap for any empirical approach.
- Ad non-observational models: The section quotes and
  paraphrases a series of authors from the 20th /21st  century which
  question the validity of the data obtained by an individual by his own introspection.

  This seems to me an even more grave objection to
  consider introspection an empirical approach.

  On the other hand, in the paper [The empirical case against introspection](https://philarchive.org/archive/PEETEC-2) Rik Peels presents his arguments why certain objections fail which are raised against the reliability of results from introspection.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about Dilthey

> “The Rise of Hermeneutics” of 1900 that the inner intelligibility of
> lived experience does not yet constitute full understanding.
> Self-understanding must also be mediated from without. The way we
> express ourselves, whether in communication or in action, is a crucial
> intermediary in defining ourselves. Understanding can only be reliable
> if it proceeds through the interpretation of human objectifications.
> Thus we properly understand ourselves not through introspection but
> through historical contextualization.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dilthey/

Also

> According to Brentano, introspection is a wrong and useless method.

The nuances of this helped birth phenomenology

> . In observation, we direct our full attention to a phenomenon in
> order to apprehend it accurately. But with objects of inner perception
> this is absolutely impossible. This is especially clear with regard to
> certain mental phenomena such as anger. If someone is in a state in
> which he wants to observe his own anger raging within him, the anger
> must already be somewhat diminished, and so his original object of
> observation would have disappeared. (1874: 29-­‐30 [I, 40-­‐1])

Comment: sorry, i read about this decades ago